# Using onmousedown to trigger simple animation

Tags: javascript, html

This is a simple function to move an element (an image) across the screen from left to right when a button is held down.

```
function moveRight () {
  var element = document.getElementById("dragged");
    var position = document.getElementById("dragged").style.left;
  if (position == 1175)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    element.style.left = position + "1px";
    position++;
  }
}
```

Code for the button:

```
<button type-"button" onmousedown="moveRight()" onmouseup="returnToCentre()" onclick="returnToCentre()"> Click me!
</button>
```

Initial position of the image element:

```
  left:20px;
  bottom:6px;
```

When I hold the button down, it moves to the left instantly, and upon release it returns to the center. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I want the left position to change from 20px to 1175px as an animation, one pixel at a time.
Note: New to JS, please give simple answers without JQuery solutions.

Comment: Excuse me: what is going wrong? What are you trying to do? What's your problem? Love the "without JQuery solutions" part.

Comment: So what is the desired effect? To have it not go back to the center?

Comment: Is it correct that the very first mousedown, you should go from 20px to 201px? Should the element keep moving while the mouse is down, since mousedown will only trigger once, then return to the center.

Comment: Yes, I want it to move as long as the mouse is kept down and to stop when the left attribute is 1175 pixels, and if it's released before, it returns to center.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (position == 1175)
    {
       return false;
    }
```

does that code ever get executed?  Looking at your code it seems like the value of position be something like "1175px".  Also what about this:

```
element.style.left = position + "1px";
```

that statement is going to concatenate two strings together.  So if the value of position is an integer, say 5, element.style.left will be "51px";  I think it's likely some form of data format inconsistency that is causing your problems.  You can easily log out the values when you run your code to see what you're getting instead of what you're expecting.

Comment: I hadn't realised that, thanks for pointing it out. If I just made it position +1,  How do I make it so that the left attribute in style is changed accordingly? As in, will it recognize the value 51 as 51px, and if not, how do I make it change the pixel value?